# Why is Bach Anh 118 "Bb Major" while Anh 119 is "G minor"?

Tags: key-signatures

Both have the same key signature, but Bach Anh 118 is "Minuet in Bb Major", while Anh 119 is "Polonaise in G minor". Why?
In general, how does one tell?

Comment: The accepted answer in the related question is what you need: look at the end of the piece. To be "in a key" means that one pitch serves as the resting point or point of stability. Naturally, the end of a piece is where the most stability is desired.

Comment: Thanks. I'm newbie and didn't even know the significance of the end note. I just checked the two pieces and indeed, one ended with Bb, the other G. Although that related discussion helps, this comment from you really made it clear to me, because over there they talk about songs and chords.